# R Shiny radioButtons how to change the colors of some of the choices?

Tags: shiny

```
ui <- fluidPage(
         radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
                       c("Normal" = "norm",
                        "Uniform" = "unif",
                        "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                        "Exponential" = "exp")))

server <- function(input, output) {}
```

I would like the font colors of "Normal" and "Uniform" to be different than those of the other choices. Let's say the color of the first two choices should be red.

Anyone who can achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just look at the examples in `?radioButtons`. This will give you instructions on how to apply `HTML` tags to choices.

To summarize, you will have to use the arguments `choiceNames` and `choiceValues`.

- `choiceNames` defines the ui of your radiobuttons. You can use `HTML` tags (`tags$strong`, `tags$code`, ... and `HTML("some html string")`)
- `choiceValues` are the values that will be recieved by the server via `input$dist`.

Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    radioButtons(
      inputId = "dist",
      label = "Distribution type:",
      choiceNames = list(
        HTML("<font color='red'>Normal</font>"), 
        tags$span(style = "color:red", "Uniform"), 
        "Log-normal", "Exponential"
      ),
      choiceValues = c("norm", "unif", "lnorm", "exp")
    )
  ),
  server = function(...) {}
)
```

Also, take a look at `shinyWidgets::shinyWidgetsGallery()` if you need inspiration for the styling of your `radioButton`s.