# Updating chloropleth map based on radio button input

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am creating a shiny dashboard to visualize the spread of COOVID 19 across the states of Australia.

The following is my data frame (covid_cases) with the number of confirmed cases, deaths and recoveries

```
  region                       Confirmed Deaths Recovered
  <chr>                            <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Australian Capital Territory       113      3       110
2 New South Wales                   4218     53      3118
3 Northern Territory                  33      0        31
4 Queensland                        1157      6      1141
5 South Australia                    468      4       462
6 Tasmania                           230     13       217
7 Victoria                         20149    787     18901
8 Western Australia                  676      9       651
```

In my server, I join the covid_cases data frame with the shapefile and color the states using the 'Cofirmed' cases. This works fine.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$ausmap <- renderLeaflet({
    states_data <-  read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rowanhogan/australian-states/master/states.geojson") %>%
      dplyr::left_join(covid_cases, by=c("STATE_NAME" = "region"))
    pal <- colorQuantile("Blues", domain = states_data$Confirmed)
    leaflet(states_data) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor=~pal(Confirmed),
                  fillOpacity=0.8,
                  color="white", weight=1) %>%
      fitBounds(110.246193, -50.322817, 155.226126, -9.088012)
    
  })

}
```

However, I now want to color the states based on user input. And Have implemented the following radioGroupButtons in my UI component.

```
UI <- dashboradBody(
fluidRow(
                radioGroupButtons(
                  inputId = "casetype",
                  label = NULL,
                  choices = c("Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"),
                  selected = "Confirmed"
                ),
                leafletOutput("ausmap")
                )
)
```

and updated my server as follows

```
  server <- function(input, output) {
      
  output$ausmap <- renderLeaflet({
    states_data <-  read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rowanhogan/australian-states/master/states.geojson") %>%
      dplyr::left_join(covid_cases, by=c("STATE_NAME" = "region"))
    pal <- colorQuantile("Blues", domain = states_data$Confirmed)
    leaflet(states_data) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor=~pal(input$casetype),
                  fillOpacity=0.8,
                  color="white", weight=1) %>%
      fitBounds(110.246193, -50.322817, 155.226126, -9.088012)
    
  })

}
```

This gives me an error stating "'x' must be numeric".

I would also like to change the color palette based on the input (ex: deaths - red, confirmed -blue, recovered - green). But am unsure how to update this.

Comment: In terms of changing the colors for groupradiobutton, you can follow the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616376/r-shiny-radiobuttons-how-to-change-the-colors-of-some-of-the-choices

Comment: I was trying to solve your other issue but was constantly getting an error:

Warning in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 1: schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
Warning: Error in : Cannot open "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rowanhogan/australian-states/master/states.geojson"; The file doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if it's the best way (somehow it feels like this should be done with reactive values, but I am still trying to figure out the details of shiny ... especially the reactive details :D) ... anyways ... here is a solution that should work :)

The trick was to use helper variables for the `casetype` and `pal`. The error you got (numeric input) was, because pal needs the numeric data (deaths,...) to map the color and not the category (casetype)

```
output$ausmap <- leaflet::renderLeaflet({
    url <- paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rowanhogan/",
                 "australian-states/master/states.geojson")

    selected_col <- switch(input$casetype,
                           "Confirmed"="Blues",
                           "Deaths"="Reds",
                           "Recovered"="Greens")

    states_data <-  sf::read_sf(url) %>%
      dplyr::left_join(covid_cases %>%
                         dplyr::select(region,selected=input$casetype),
                       by=c("STATE_NAME" = "region"))
    pal <- leaflet::colorQuantile(selected_col, domain = states_data$selected)
    leaflet::leaflet(states_data) %>%
      leaflet::addTiles() %>%
      leaflet::addPolygons(fillColor=~pal(selected),
                           fillOpacity=0.8,
                           color="white",
                           weight=1) %>%
      leaflet::fitBounds(110.246193, -50.322817, 155.226126, -9.088012)

  })
```